# Query MS Access DB from Excel VBA - How to return 0 if no value found?

Tags: excel, null, vba

I'm querying an MS Access database from within excel VBA. I need it to return 0 in excel if no record exists in the DB. This is my code:

```
Function CheckIfDateExistInDB(MyDate As Date) As Date
Dim strSql As String

strSql = "SELECT Date FROM AccessDB WHERE Date = #" & MyDate & "#"

Set AccessRS = AccessCN.Execute(strSql)
CheckIfDateExistInDB = AccessRS.Fields(0)
Set AccessRS = Nothing
End Function
```

Please help -
1) This code returns "#VALUE!" in excel if the record does not exist in the DB.
2) If the record does not exist, this query takes a LONG time to run.
3) I need the code to return 0 if no record exists (and speed it up).

Comment: For speed, it's all relative. Does it take 10 secs, 30 secs, 1 min? And how is your connection set up? Does query run as long in Access? What are its size, indices, structure? Also, Date is a reserved Access word, consider escaping with brackets: `[Date]`.

Comment: Adding an index did speed things up considerably

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider conditionally wrapping recordset by [recordcount](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms676701(v=vs.85).aspx) property during field retrieval:

```
Dim AccessCN As Object, AccessRS As Object

Set AccessCN = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set AccessRS = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

AccessCN.Open "DRIVER=Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb);" _
                & "DBQ=C:\Path\To\Database\File.accdb;"
AccessRS.Open "SELECT Date FROM AccessDB WHERE Date = #" & MyDate & "#", AccessCN

If AccessRS.RecordCount > 0 Then
     CheckIfDateExistInDB = AccessRS.Fields(0)
Else
     CheckIfDateExistInDB = 0
End If

AccessRS.Close

Set AccessRS = Nothing
Set AccessCN = Nothing
```

Comment: AccessRS.RecordCount returns a value of '-1'. That means ADO cannot determine the number of records or if the provider or cursor type does not support RecordCount. Any way to get around this? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms676701(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Whoops, missed that you are running [ADO execute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675023%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) instead of [ADO open](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675544%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) recordset method. The former's recordset is slightly limited being a read-only, forward-only cursor. I updated for the latter which has RecordCount available.

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks again. I just had to add the CN to the RS.Open string: AccessRS.Open strSql, AccessCN